# can not use kafka for python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

**python:2.6.6**

**kafka-python:1.4.3**

**i had run the kafka producer,but it always tips me this error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "KafkaOperation.py", line 11, in
>
> from kafka import KafkaProducer
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/**init**.py", line 21, in
>
> from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/**init**.py",
>   line 5, in
>
> from kafka.consumer.group import KafkaConsumer
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line
>   13, in
>
> from kafka.consumer.fetcher import Fetcher
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/fetcher.py",
>   line 19, in
>
> from kafka.record import MemoryRecords
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/record/**init**.py", line
>   1, in
>
> from kafka.record.memory_records import MemoryRecords
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/record/memory_records.py",
>   line 27, in
>
> from kafka.record.default_records import DefaultRecordBatch,
>   DefaultRecordBatchBuilder
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/record/default_records.py",
>   line 338, in
>
> class DefaultRecordBatchBuilder(DefaultRecordBase,
>   ABCRecordBatchBuilder):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/kafka/record/default_records.py",
>   line 378, in DefaultRecordBatchBuilder
>
> byte_like=(bytes, bytearray, memoryview),
>
> **NameError: name 'memoryview' is not defined**

**the codes these:**

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError
import json

class Kafka_producer():

    def __init__(self, kafkahost,kafkaport, kafkatopic):
        self.kafkatopic = kafkatopic
        service_host = kafkahost+":"+kafkaport
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=service_host)

    def sendjsondata(self, params):
        try:
            # parmas_message = json.dumps(params)
            producer = self.producer
            futur = producer.send(self.kafkatopic, params.encode('utf-8'))
            res = futur.get(timeout=60)
            producer.flush()
            producer.close()
        except KafkaError as e:
            print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test = {
    #     "test":"testtets"
    # }
    # Kafka_producer("http://10.25.245.192","9092","nori-log").sendjsondata(test)
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='10.25.245.192:9092')
    for _ in range(100):
        producer.send('nori-log', {"test":"test_content"})
```

**And i had exchange the toronto version to 2.2.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [memoryview](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview-type) type is new in Python 2.7.  Python 2.6.6 is [almost 8 years old](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/) at this point, and [hasn't gotten any support or security updates for almost 5 years](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0361/).  You need to upgrade your Python installation.

Comment: yes，i had checked it ,you should must change your python version to at least 2.7,and it will be work.